# Deploying Angular 6 app to linux shared hosting (Apache server)

Tags: linux, apache, angular6, shared-hosting

Not trying to duplicate the existing questions on "Deploying Angular apps"
I am trying to deploy an Angular 6 app to shared hosting on go daddy.
I see a blank page after i upload the files to public folder
I have tried the following troubleshooting steps
1. https://angular.io/guide/deployment#production-servers
2. https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2
3. [Unable to deploy Angular 5 using dist folder in WAMP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115124/unable-to-deploy-angular-5-using-dist-folder-in-wamp-server)
4. I have tried changing the path on `<base href="./">`
5. Used the `ng build --prod` command to create the files in dist folder and uploaded them aas it is to the public www folder then created the .htaccess folder and rewritten rule as per angular docs
Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Nothing seems to solve the problem.
Has anyone deployed an angular2+ app on godaddy shared linux hosting (apache server) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the routing.
I was routing using localhost as route URL.
It had nothing to do with the server setup